# How to hide the keyboard when I press return key in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

Clicking in a textfield makes the keyboard appear.
How do I hide it when the user presses the return key?

Comment: The nice thing about Stack Overflow is that MANY questions have already been answered, especially simple ones. Therefore, please look for answers FIRST, before asking. See, it's simple: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+hide+keyboard

Comment: This is a subclass of UITextfield that dynamically change the UIReturnKey according to text/string condition:
https://github.com/codeinteractiveapps/OBReturnKeyTextField

Comment: @Felixyz, The first question there is ironically about Android.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I suppose that might change from year to year. But it's nice to get a reply one decade later :) Not so nice to discover I wrote such a snarky comment ten years ago. (In my defense, perhaps, it wasn't as clear back then that snark is a rot that perpetually threatens to destroy everything that is nice about the internet.)

Comment: @Felixyz, Don't worry, I know the feeling :D

Answer (score 299, accepted):

First make your file delegate for UITextField

```
@interface MYLoginViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

Then add this method to your code.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {        
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Also add `self.textField.delegate = self;`

Comment: Curious, why is <UITextFieldDelegate> not necessary? Usually you'll see a warning in this case.

Comment: if you make your file delegate using Interface Builder then <UITextFieldDelegate> is not necessary in .h file..

Comment: adding <UITextFieldDelegate> in .h file and set delegate in viewdidload [yourTextField setDelegate:self]; will complete it!

Comment: @Saurabh What's so special about storyboard created VC?

Answer (score 63):

In `viewDidLoad` declare:

`[yourTextField setDelegate:self];`

Then, include the override of the delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `setDelegate:` reminder. Definitely had forgotten and code wasn't working previously.

Comment: Shouldn't this be textField, rather than yourTextField as it is being passed in?

Comment: is a way of saying that declare the delegate of your textField

Comment: <UITextFieldDelegate> should be in .h file, otherwise warning will appear!

Answer (score 24):

Try this in **Swift**,

**Step 1:** Set delegate as self to your `textField`

```
textField.delegate = self
```

**Step 2:** Add this UITextFieldDelegate below your class declaration,

```
extension YourClassName: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In swift do like this:
First in your `ViewController` implement this `UITextFieldDelegate`
For eg.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
....
}
```

Now add a delegate to a `TextField` in which you want to dismiss the keyboard when return is tapped either in `viewDidLoad` method like below or where you are initializing it.
For eg.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()   
    myTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Now add this method.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Second step not necessery if you set delegate in IB.

Comment: Appears (in current versions of Swift) there should be an underscore before "textField:"

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 4

Set delegate of `UITextField` in view controller, `field.delegate = self`, and then:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // don't force `endEditing` if you want to be asked for resigning
        // also return real flow value, not strict, like: true / false
        return textField.endEditing(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you handle wanting users to 'tab' to the next text field with the press of the return key, until the last one and then it resigns ? Also in SwiftUI.

Comment: @Learn2Code make a manager, collect textfields and chain, the last one will trigger finish function.

Answer (score 2):

set delegate of `UITextField`, and over ride, `textFieldShouldReturn` method, in that method just write following two lines:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

that's it. Before writing a code dont forget to set delegate of a `UITextField` and set Return key type to "Done" from properties window.(command + shift + I).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
[textField setDelegate: self];
```

Then, in textField delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: that is not the best practice to do that.

Comment: needs UITextFieldDelegate in the interface definition.

Comment: @AlpAltunel: Thanks for the comment, It was 4 years back.

Answer (score 2):

Define this class and then set your text field to use the class and this automates the whole hiding keyboard when return is pressed automatically.

```
class TextFieldWithReturn: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate
{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) 
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Then all you need to do in the storyboard is set the fields to use the class:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can connect "Primary Action Triggered" (right click on UITextField) with an IBAction and you can resign first responder (without delegation). Example
(Swift 4):

```
@IBAction func textFieldPrimaryAction(_ sender: UITextField) {
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Preferred way if using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think for a novice things might be a bit confusing. I think the correct answer is a mix of all the above, at least in Swift4.

Either create an extension or use the ViewController in which you'd like to use this but make sure to implement UITextFieldDelegate. For reusability's sake I found it easier to use an extension:

```
extension UIViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    ...
}
```

> but the alternative works as well:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

Add the method textFieldShouldReturn (depending on your previous option, either in the extension or in your ViewController)

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return textField.endEditing(false)
}
```

In your viewDidLoad method, set the textfield's delegate to self

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ..
    myTextField.delegte = self;
    ..
}
```

That should be all. Now, when you press `return` the `textFieldShouldReturn` should be called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the keyboard for a particular keyboard use 
`[self.view resignFirstResponder];`
If you want to hide any keyboard from view use `[self.view endEditing:true];`

Answer (score 0):

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Use this