# Hide keyboard when hitting return key in IOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have tried this solution to hide keyboard but it doesn't work...

[How to hide the keyboard when i press return key in a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573955/how-can-i-hide-keyboard-when-i-press-return-key)

Many thanks

Comment: Lets see some code, how do you have everything linked up?

Comment: what controls are you using? UITextField, UITextArea, ...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

assuming you are using UITextField, how do you create the textfield? is it by xib? or by code? make sure you implement UITextFieldDelegate in your class

```
@interface YouClass : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

if its xib,  connect your textField to the file owner's delegate. and also connect your File owner to your IBOutlet UITextField

[image]

if its by code. just do

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

now implement

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Answer (score 0):

Just resign as first responder in your input text field, when the return key pressed. The keyboard will dismissed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Return button to actual built in function type. In one of my apps I have set it as a "Done" button because when the user has finished they can press this and it will drop the keyboard away. To set this add this to your code in somewhere like the -(void)viewDidLoad; method.

```
textFieldName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

That should then give you a blue done button on the keyboard that hides it.