# How to hide keyboard when user taping return key

Tags: ios, swift

i'm a swift programmer, i have UIAlertViewController With two text fields and i want that when user taping enter , keyboard hide . but i don't know what i should do. its my code

```
 var alert = UIAlertController(title: "خوش آمدید", message: "لطفا نام و نام خانوادگی خود را نام ببرید" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var act = UIAlertAction(title: "تایید", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {(ACTION) in
            var name = alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
            var lname = alert.textFields![1] as! UITextField
            self.namet = name.text
            self.lnamet = lname.text
            if (self.lnamet == "" && self.namet == "")
            {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            self.defaults.setObject("done", forKey: "dn")
            var fulltext = " خوش اومدی " + self.namet + self.lnamet
            self.txt.text = fulltext
            var ntfc = UILocalNotification()
            ntfc.alertBody = "  برگرد  " + self.namet + "!"
            ntfc.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 40)
            ntfc.soundName = "Untitled.m4a"
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(ntfc)
        })
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "نام"
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        }



        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField1) -> Void in
            textField1.placeholder = "نام خانوادگی"
            textField1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573955/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-when-i-press-return-key-in-a-uitextfield

Comment: i said swift, not objective c

Comment: view.endEditing(true) is handy as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your ViewController implement this `UITextFieldDelegate`
For eg.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
....
}
```

Now add a delegate to a TextField in which you want to dismiss the keyboard when return is tapped either in viewDidLoad method like below or where you are initialising it.
For eg.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Now add this method.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```