# First Responder Of Two Textfields

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

So in a small app I am making, if the user clicks the sign in button, two text fields pop up from the bottom of the screen(the username and the password textfields). Now I want the keyboard to pop up automatically as well when the user clicks on the sign in button. To do this I said:

```
self.userNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Now for some reason I can't click on the userNameTextField. The cursor is always stuck on the passwordTextField. I think this is because it is making the password text field the first responder so it won't let me click on the username one. Is there any other way to automatically bring up the keyboard without using this firstResponder method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by doing what you described here you are making `userNameTextField` a first responder, and right after that you are making `passwordTextField` a first responder - which ends up having `passwordTextField` set as first responder (because Swift is lightning fast and you can't even notice the moment when `userNameTextField` becomes a first responder).
So, pick which one will you call (probably `self.userNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` because you want user to type the username first) and then you could call `resignFirstResponder()` (which will resign `userNameTextField` from being a first responder when user taps the "Return" on the keyboard) by implementing `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldReturn` (let me know if you need some help there) and right after that call `self.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` to make your `passwordTextField` a first responder so that user can type a password.

Comment: Oh I see so in the text field delegate I would say: `userNameTF.resignFirstResponder();` `passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder();` But then when the user clicks on the return key when the password textField is the firstResponder then the code in the text field delegate is not correct right? Maybe I can have some boolean variable which keeps track of which text field is the first responder and I can resign or become the first responder in the textfield delegate method.

Comment: You are almost there. Correct steps would be:
1) Conform to UITextFieldDelegate and set your controller as a delegate to the both of your text fields
1a) Check here how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573955/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-when-i-press-return-key-in-a-uitextfield
2) Set self.userNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
3) When you detect that userNameTextField tapped "Return", resign it (like in this answer I've sent you) and call passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks, I think I got it now.